# Jackson cannot map JSON to Object in Java

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jackson

I am trying to map the following JSON string to a pojo class:

```
{
    "Data": {
        "brand": "Porsche",
        "model": 2020,
        "color": "gray"
    },
    "Section": {
        "location": "UK",
        "service": "London"
    },
    // other elements 
}
```

I am **only** interested in 2 fields (brand, model) in the `Data` part and want to map these 2 fields to the following model:

***Data:***

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Data {

    @JsonProperty("brand")
    private String brand;

    @JsonProperty("model")
    private int model;
}
```

However, although `jsonString` has a valid JSON, the fields in `Data` are null or empty.

```
// jsonString is a valid JSON string read from a REST API via WebClient
String jsonString = request.block(); 
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Data data = mapper.readValue(value, Data.class);
```

So, what is missing? Is there any problem regarding to pojo fields or annotations in it? Could you help me pls?

Comment: That JSON is not a `Data` object, and the *I am **only** interested in 2 fields (brand, model) in the `Data` part* doesn't seem to be addressed in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not specified any class to catch the response. You have only created 1 model to catch the Data object.
You can do it like this,

i) Create a class to catch the JSON,

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Payload {

    @JsonProperty("Data")
    private Data data;

  
}
```

You have to first catch the JSON using the Payload class and then parse it accordingly,

```
String jsonString = request.block(); 
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Payload payload = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Payload.class);
Data data = payload.getData();
```

ii) Without any extra class,

```
String payloadString = "{\n" +
                "    \"Data\": {\n" +
                "        \"brand\": \"Porsche\",\n" +
                "        \"model\": 2020,\n" +
                "        \"color\": \"gray\"\n" +
                "    },\n" +
                "    \"Section\": {\n" +
                "        \"location\": \"UK\",\n" +
                "        \"service\": \"London\"\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "}";
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, Object> objectMap = objectMapper.readValue(payloadString, HashMap.class);
        String dataString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(objectMap.get("Data"));
        Data data = objectMapper.readValue(dataString, Data.class);
        System.out.println(data);
```